Why do I get "inf" values after replacing NaN values in my dataset with the mean or median?
I'm using Python and I have a dataset containing NaN values. To clean up these data, I replaced the NaN values with the mean or median of each column using the fillna() function from pandas. However, after this operation, some values in my dataset became "inf". I don't understand why this is happening and how I can fix this issue.

Check if there are some columns that all of it is nan values, this could be a reason why you get inf when you replace them with mean or median (if all the values are nan there is no meaning in mean or meadian)
Also if you can provide more information, it would be useful to check what are the potential problems in the task you're doing.

I checked but i didn't find any columns that all of it is  nan

If you provide some parts of your code and data I can help you better I think.
